# Python BigQuery API: how to get data asynchronously?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am getting started with the BigQuery API in Python, [following the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#overview).

This is my code, adapted from [an example](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-api-quickstart#query):

```
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
bigquery_service = build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)

try:
    query_request = bigquery_service.jobs()
    query_data = {
        'query': (
            'SELECT * FROM [mytable] LIMIT 10;"
        )
    }
    query_response = query_request.query(
        projectId=project_id,
        body=query_data).execute()
    for row in query_response['rows']:
        print('\t'.join(field['v'] for field in row['f']))
```

The problem I'm having is that I keep getting the response:

```
{u'kind': u'bigquery#queryResponse', 
 u'jobComplete': False, 
u'jobReference': {u'projectId': 'myproject', u'jobId': u'xxxx'}}
```

So it has no `rows` field. Looking at the docs, I guess I need to take the `jobId` field and use it to check when the job is complete, and then get the data.

The problem I'm having is that the docs are a bit scattered and confusing, and I don't know how to do this.

I think I need to [use this method](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/get) to check the status of the job, but how do I adapt it for Python? And how often should I check / how long should I wait?

Could anyone give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is code to do what you want [here](https://code.google.com/p/bigquery-e2e/source/browse/samples/ch07/query.py).

If you want more background on what it is doing, check out Google BigQuery Analytics chapter 7 (the relevant snippet is available [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=LDaiAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA202&dq=google%20bigquery%20analytics%20getQueryResults&pg=PA202#v=onepage&q&f=false).)

**TL;DR:**

Your initial `jobs.query()` call is returning before the query completes; to wait for the job to be done you'll need to poll on `jobs.getQueryResults()`. You can then page through the results of that call.